# R - Stuck in a IF Else

Tags: r

I am stuck in an exercise that askes me to read a data frame and write an ifelse statement that returns 1 if the sex (theres a gender column) is Female and 2 if the sex is Male. Then the exercise askes me the sum() of theses numbers. No success so far. Any  help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please help us help you by providing us code that lets us reproduce your problem, and if possible give us code you have tried so far so we can see where you got stuck.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please read [ask] and give a [mre] in your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
## define data frame
df <- data.frame(
  id=c(1,2,3,4,5),
  gender=c("Male","Female","Male","Female","Male")
)

## male=1,female=2
sum(ifelse(df$gender == "Male",1,2))
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much Caio.